# UIDatePicker change AM/PM designation case

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I need to display a `UIDatePicker` in `UIDatePickerModeTime`.

```
TimePicker= [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[TimePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(TimeChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
TimePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
TimePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
[self.view addSubview:imePicker];
```

It works but it shows the DatePicker with `AM/PM` options. Can we change the `AM/PM` to lower case (ie. `am/pm`)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the only way to do this would be with a UIPickerView with 3 columns: one for the hour, one for minutes, and the other for your "am/pm". The right form is with capitals though, which is why you don't have a choice.